# How can I remove this CSS rule from within a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, css, greasemonkey

[image]

I've got the element, say

`var center = document.getElementById('contentArea');`

What do I need to call to achieve the impact of what the Firefox debugger is doing when I uncheck that box? It's not as simple as setting the width manually, because I want it to fall back on that crossed-out rule below.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to the width property which you want to take precedence.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how I would go about this? What would the command look like? `center.setAttribute...`?

Comment: Try  `$('#contentArea').css('width', '786px !important');` 
or in javascript `center .style.width= '786px !important';`

Comment: shouldn't I be targeting the `.hasRightCol` property somehow?

Comment: Its upto you which selectoryou need to target.... I used `#contentArea` and `center` coz you mentioned that selector particularly in your question

Comment: maybe I'm not using the right terminology. my essential question is "how can I simulate the behavior of firefox when unclicking that box?". The line above doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Unticking css property on any browser's dev tool is similar to commenting it in .css file. If you can't change your CSS file, then the only option you are left with is to override it as mentioned above.

Comment: You can also remove the CSS property using something like `$('yourSelector').css('width', '');` but it must be inline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75605/discussion-between-g-akshay-and-rodericday).